# Ground Truth and training data set

Tags: machine-learning, training-data

I want to know the relation between training data set, testing data set, and gound truth. I know the meaning of each one separately but I cannot see the relation between them especially ground truth and training data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your training data is what you train your classifier on.

You then test the accuracy of your model on your test set.

Ground truth refers to the label for each training sample you have i.e. you know which category/outcome each training sample belongs to

Comment: What if I cannot know the label of each sample in my training data? Cannot I still process with it?

Comment: You can, but you'd want to look at something called unsupervised learning at that point.  For supervised learning you need labels because otherwise it can't learn that features x, y, z are associated with category 1 for example.

Comment: I have another question, if I know the label of parts of my training? Can I consider that part as ground truth and process with the complete training set?

Comment: you need the labels for all training data. If you only know labels for some of your samples, then they are the only samples that you can use in your training set

Comment: @Simon What is Ground Truth in clustering?

Comment: @KouchakYazdi Because clustering is unsupervised leanring, you don't need ground-truth for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we need to train a machine to classify apples from oranges. The machine-learning way is to "show" the machine some examples of oranges and apples (training set),based on which it identifies the rest as either oranges or apples (restrict yourself to apples and oranges only!). Now, the ground-truth is the labels you adjudged as apples and oranges(in the training set).

Answer (score 1):

Ground Truth is factual data that has been observed or measured, and can be analyzed objectively. It has not been inferred. If the data is based on an assumption, subject to opinion, or up for discussion, then, by definition, that is not Ground Truth data.

Your ability to solve a problem using data science depends tremendously on how you frame the problem and discerning without ambiguity, if you can establish Ground Truth. more information is detailed here [The Importance of Ground Truth in Data Science](http://crowdsourcing.topcoder.com/the-importance-of-ground-truth-in-data-science/)

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

There is another important use of the term 'ground truth' where in regression problems it is very valuable to know the true deterministic component of the data to be modeled.